# Confused about participants/signers when using Accounts library with Tokens SDK

Tags: corda

I just started reading/experimenting with the **Accounts** library yesterday and trying to wrap my head around the **participants/signers** part in my states.
Let's say I have the following:
1. **Mint:** A node that issues tokens.
2. **Registry:** A node that hosts accounts and generates key pairs for them when requested.
3. **Wallet:** A node that holds tokens on behalf of accounts.
4. I created my own fungible token which basically has an extra field: `PublicKey owningAccount`

The process:
1. The **Registry** creates a new account (let's call it **Account001**), so the **Registry** is the `host` of that account.
2. The **Mint** requests a new key pair for **Account001** from **Registry**
3. The **Mint** issues a new token to **Wallet** and sets **owningAccount** to the key they got for **Account001** from **Registry**, so now **Wallet** is the `holder` of the token

So now we have:
1. **Registry** is the `host` of **Account001**
2. **Wallet** is the `holder` of the token (on behalf of **Account001**)

Questions:
1. Is my approach of having those 3 nodes correct? One node controls the supply of tokens, another the users, and last one tracks the "balances" of tokens per user.
2. I want to keep this separation of nodes (assuming it's conceptually correct); and for that reason I don't want to include the **owningAccount** as part of the **participants** for the token, so the token will only persist in the vault of **Wallet**, **BUT** I will require **owningAccount** as a signer for various commands (e.g. when moving the token to a new **owningAccount**; both the `holder` (i.e. **Wallet**) and the owner (i.e. **Registry** on behalf of **owningAccount**) must sign).
3. In general (let's forget about tokens), if I have a node that manages users and another that manages the state that has **owningAccount** field, in that state do I need to have **owningAccount** as a participant? Like I mentioned I'm still trying to figure out the "right" approach (usually things become more clear as I program more), but I would imagine that there should be some decoupling where the **owningAccount** is just required as a signer for commands related to states that are tied to it, and the **participant** is mostly just the node to whom that state was issued to.

Comment: Not sure i understand the distinction between registry and wallet? How does the wallet hold tokens on behalf of accounts if the account private keys are held by another node? Furthermore, as the keys were generated by the registry node, none of the transactions pertaining to stated owned by those keys will be considered "relevant" for the wallet node. You need to combine the function of the wallet and registry node.

Comment: @RogerWillis
**1. Users Registry** node's sole purpose is to create **AccountInfo** states and provide other nodes with this state and also generate new pairs of public/private keys when requested.  **2. Mint** will request a new public key for a certain account from **Users Registry** then issue a new token where: **Holder** = **Wallet Node**, **Owning Account** = **Public key provided by Accounts Registry**.  This way I will have 3 nodes with separate duties (create user accounts, mint new tokens, hold balances of users).

Comment: For the above structure I just want to make sure that **A.** it's a good design, **B.** The token participants list only contains the holder (i.e. **Wallet Node**), **C.** while for any command on that token we require 2 signers (the holder **Wallet Node** and the owningAccount which is **Users Registry** node which holds the private key of the owningAccount). What do you think?

Comment: I was also experimenting on similar grounds. However I am still on very early stage, the amount of time I have spend with cordapps, I understand the the transactions are signed by the node and sent to the receiver node. In case an Account001 wants to send Assets to Account002, which node here will be signer (I suppose it will be the (registry + wallet) node)? Now which node will be the receiver considering both the accounts belong to same registry.

Comment: @AshishMishra
A token has a `Holder` (which is of type `AbstractParty`) so in your case when you are transferring from `Account001` to `Account002` you are right that we are transferring inside the same node (let's call it `Wallet` node) but the public keys that own `Account001` and `Account002` are different.

Comment: Remember that a Party is a combination of `CordaX500Name: Wallet, London, GB` and a `Public Key` so even though the old and new Holder of the token is `Wallet, London, GB` the public key in the input state is `Public key of Account001` and the public key in the output state (i.e. the state that is now with the new owner) is `Public Key of Account002`. So for that token move to happen; the old owner must sign, so `Wallet, London, GB` will sign on behalf of `Account001` using the `public key of Account001`. Sorry for repeating myself lol

Comment: @AdelRustum thanks for the explanation. Much clear now. In this case, since Corda is not a like a true distributed blockchain where all the nodes has all the Transactions. In Corda nodes get transactions only on a need-to-know basis, so in the case we are discussing only Node-1 will have the transactions related to Account001 and Account002. So if Node-1 is damaged, the data is gone? This is catastrophic. I know externally you can have applications to replicate the node/storage to a passive node but that fails the purpose of blockchain which should inherently take care of Distribution.

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm not sure how the "on a need to know basis" and "data availability/backup" work together in Corda.

Answer (score 1):

Roger Willis explained to me on Slack how FungibleToken allows assigning the token to a certain owner (i.e. public key) as opposed to a Party by using the **Holder** attribute; the process is as follows:
1. The **Mint** node starts the `issue token` flow which takes as inputs amount and AccountInfo ref
2. It requests a new public key for the referenced AccountInfo from the **Accounts Registry** node
3. The received public key is used to get the respective party (i.e. `identityService.partyFromKey(receivedPublicKey)`)
4. The resulting party is assigned as the **Holder** of the token
5. Remember that a **Party** is the CordaX500Name (**Accounts Registry** in our case) and a public key that identifies this entity (in our case it's the public key that mapps to an **AccountInfo** state (i.e. to a certain user)).
6. So whenever we issue a new token, the holder will always be **Accounts Registry** party but the same party will have different public keys for different owners/users.
7. With all that being said we no longer need 2 nodes **Accounts Registry** and **Wallets**, we will have one node **Wallets** which holds our **AccountInfo** states and our tokens where the holder of the tokens is **Wallets** party but the public key in that party will vary and map to different **AccountInfo** states depending on who's the owner/user.